# Ask for input then open in new window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I don't know much JavaScript so I was just wondering if it would be possible for a Java alert to pop up asking for a URL and then set the iframe arc to the URL (this will run as a bookmarklet).

Basically, I am looking for a prompt to pop up asking for a url and then open a new window and create an iframe in the new window with the arc that was typed earlier l.

javascript:

```js
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<style>body {margin: 0;}</style>
                       <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//bing.com" frameborder="0" 
                       sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts">
                       </iframe>');
```

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can use a self calling function to enclose the script:

```
javascript: (function() {
var alertWinRes  =  prompt("Please enter Site", "bing.com");
if(alertWinRes !== null){
   var win = window.open("My new Window"); 
   win.document.write('<style>body {margin: 0;} 
   </style><iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//' + alertWinRes + 
   '" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-forms                        
   allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>');     
 }
})();
```

The same functionality can be achieved without iframe:

```
javascript: (function() {
var alertWinRes  =  prompt("Please enter Site", "bing.com");
if(alertWinRes !== null){
   var win = window.open("https://" + alertWinRes, "_blank");     
}
})();
```

Using prompt creates an alert the user can use to enter the text and the second parameter is used to set a default. You'll have to have website already open for this to trigger, for security reasons in a new tab it doesn't work (there's work arounds posted online about it if needed).

Comment: Could you add that to the existing code, it would just be really helpful, I don’t know JavaScript to well, thank you.

Comment: What I mean is could you change the iframe arc to the answer from the prompt?

Comment: Hello, I seemed to have gotten a notification from you or somebody on the topic but I do not see the comment.

Comment: I just updated the answer with your code in it to open a window

Comment: You could also just replace the iframe with window.open(URL, '_blank'); where URL is the string the user adds plus the "https://" in front of it and pretty much would be the same functionality

Comment: I would love that, but I need the iframe so that your searches do not go to your history.